# Is there any scientific results on the difficulty of picking elements from a list?

Tags: drop-down-list, measuring, cognitive-load, picker

I am looking for a reasonably formal study of the impact of the number of elements in a list (e.g. a dropdown menu) on the time, effort, and loss of comfort for the user whose task it is to pick one element in the list.

I'm looking for something akin to [Fitt's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_law) or Dreyfus' [the measure of man's part on basic data reading](http://design.data.free.fr/RUCHE/documents/Ergonomie%20Henry%20DREYFUS.pdf) in terms of scientific process.

Comment: The scope of this research is small enough that there might not be a formal published paper on it. All I’ve read before are results form usability studies.

Comment: What search terms did use searching for papers/articles? For example from Google Scholar? So we don't duplicate the work you've already done.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for [Hick's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hick%27s_law): Increasing the number of choices increases the decision time logarithmically.

You might also want to look around at Nielsen Norman, who publish well-researched articles. [Here's one on dropdown lists.](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/listbox-dropdown/)